# emacs says on startup "apply: Spawning child process: Exec format error"

Tags: windows, emacs, gnupg

When I reopened my emacs it did not execute my .emacs file but just said

`"apply: Spawning child process: Exec format error"`

Situation: win8.1 64-bit, emacs 25.3.
Just before, I reinstalled gpg4win via enigmail's installation assistant.

In the meantime I have found out that the line

`(package-install)`

in my `.emacs` runs into this problem.  Without it, everything is "normal" but without important packages.  Also `(server-start)` works fine, for example.

As I did not do anything with the emacs I can only guess that the gpg4win installation/deinstallation/reinstallation has killed something.

But what?  Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Miracle, problem solved...

I installed an old version of GnuPG and deinstalled it again.
Now, emacs' `(package-install)` and the package manager and everything is working again.

Still, I have absolutely no clue why.